# Pandas : groupby function + rolling mean + reset index returning Nan

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df:

```
     Symbol       Time   Close  Sessions     DR  ADR
0       AMD 2019-11-18   39.88       387   1.39  NaN
1       AMD 2019-11-19   41.29       388   2.10  NaN
2       AMD 2019-11-20   40.98       389   1.68  NaN
3       AMD 2019-11-21   39.52       390   2.07  NaN
4       AMD 2019-11-22   39.15       391   1.70  NaN
...     ...        ...     ...       ...    ...  ...
1600   UPST 2021-09-03  247.29      1597  14.13  NaN
1601   UPST 2021-09-07  262.70      1598  21.90  NaN
1602   UPST 2021-09-08  274.33      1599  15.64  NaN
1603   UPST 2021-09-09  289.60      1600  29.16  NaN
1604   UPST 2021-09-10  270.46      1605  25.98  NaN
```

I would like to get the rolling 20 day average of `DR` in the `ADR` column.

My code is:

```
    df_day['ADR'] = df_day.groupby('Sessions')['DR'].rolling(20).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Returns:

```
     Symbol       Time   Close  Sessions  DR  ADR
0       AMD 2019-11-18   39.88       NaN NaN  NaN
1       AMD 2019-11-19   41.29       NaN NaN  NaN
2       AMD 2019-11-20   40.98       NaN NaN  NaN
3       AMD 2019-11-21   39.52       NaN NaN  NaN
4       AMD 2019-11-22   39.15       NaN NaN  NaN
...     ...        ...     ...       ...  ..  ...
1600   UPST 2021-09-03  247.29       NaN NaN  NaN
1601   UPST 2021-09-07  262.70       NaN NaN  NaN
1602   UPST 2021-09-08  274.33       NaN NaN  NaN
1603   UPST 2021-09-09  289.60       NaN NaN  NaN
1604   UPST 2021-09-10  270.46       NaN NaN  NaN
```

Comment: added the reset_index to resolve `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index` but obviously drops all the values I need. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you groupby by column with less like 20+ unique values per groups in column `Sessions`, so ouput is always `NaN`.

---

I think you need `groupby` by `Symbol` instead column `Sessions`, but also need groups with `20+` values.

```
df_day['ADR'] = df_day.groupby('Symbol')['DR'].rolling(20).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Solution with align by `20D` is create first `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df_day['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_day['Time'])

df_day = df_day.set_index('Time')
df_day['ADR'] = df_day.groupby('Symbol')['DR'].rolling(20, freq='D').mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

EDIT:

Test with 3days:

```
df_day['ADR'] = df_day.groupby('Symbol')['DR'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
print (df_day)
     Symbol        Time   Close  Sessions     DR        ADR
0       AMD  2019-11-18   39.88       387   1.39        NaN
1       AMD  2019-11-19   41.29       388   2.10        NaN
2       AMD  2019-11-20   40.98       389   1.68   1.723333
3       AMD  2019-11-21   39.52       390   2.07   1.950000
4       AMD  2019-11-22   39.15       391   1.70   1.816667
1600   UPST  2021-09-03  247.29      1597  14.13        NaN
1601   UPST  2021-09-07  262.70      1598  21.90        NaN
1602   UPST  2021-09-08  274.33      1599  15.64  17.223333
1603   UPST  2021-09-09  289.60      1600  29.16  22.233333
1604   UPST  2021-09-10  270.46      1605  25.98  23.593333
```

---

```
df_day['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_day['Time'])

df_day = df_day.set_index('Time')
df_day['ADR'] = df_day.groupby('Symbol')['DR'].rolling(3, freq='D').mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
print (df_day)
           Symbol   Close  Sessions     DR        ADR
Time                                                 
2019-11-18    AMD   39.88       387   1.39        NaN
2019-11-19    AMD   41.29       388   2.10        NaN
2019-11-20    AMD   40.98       389   1.68   1.723333
2019-11-21    AMD   39.52       390   2.07   1.950000
2019-11-22    AMD   39.15       391   1.70   1.816667
2021-09-03   UPST  247.29      1597  14.13        NaN
2021-09-07   UPST  262.70      1598  21.90        NaN
2021-09-08   UPST  274.33      1599  15.64  17.223333
2021-09-09   UPST  289.60      1600  29.16  22.233333
2021-09-10   UPST  270.46      1605  25.98  23.593333
```

Comment: `.rolling('20D')` got it working. It now indexes on `Time` and the actual `Time` column is NaN. is there a way to return the df to the way before the above?

Comment: resolved. thanks! Will delete unrelated comments above for readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_day['ADR'] = df_day.groupby('Sessions').rolling(20, on='DR').mean().astype(float).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Comment: @jezrael I tested it, it works, see what OP thinks

Comment: @jezrael Tested OP's gave None, mine is not None

Comment: Then OK. I think problem is something else.

Comment: tested on the updated solution suggested. ADR column still empty. b `Sessions` and `DR` are fine

Comment: appologies. just tried again, the error is now `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`